# identify harddrive before mounting

Tags: debian, scripting, usb

I've recently made 2 script that take care of mounting and dismounting a harddrive in linux. The thing that I could not figure out is the following. I am currently mounting `/dev/sdc1` to `/home/media/externalHardDrive`. The thing is, when I insert another usb device (like usb stick) while the harddrive is not being inserted it will most likely put the usb-stick on `/dev/sdc1`. I would like to learn a way to identify the device before mounting it, so I can make sure that only the harddrive is affected by this script.

These are my scripts:
**unmount_script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

MOUNT="/home/media/externalHardDrive"

if grep -qs "$MOUNT" /proc/mounts; then
  umount "$MOUNT"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "HardDrive kan veilig worden verwijderd :D"
  else
    echo "Er is iets mis gegaan, blijf overal vanaf :("
  fi
else
  echo "Er is geen HardDrive gemount op $MOUNT, deze kan daarom niet verwijderd worden!"
fi
```

**mount_script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

MOUNT="/home/media/externalHardDrive"

if grep -qs "$MOUNT" /proc/mounts; then
  echo "HardDrive is al gemount op $MOUNT ;)"
else
  mount /dev/sdc1 "$MOUNT"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "HardDrive is succesvol gemount :D"
  fi
fi
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?
I am running these scripts on a debian server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a point in time where you know your USB drive is on `/dev/sdc0` do the following:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid | grep -F /dev/sdc1
```

and note the number between the time (HH:MM) and  the `->`, lets assume its `xyz`. That `xyz` is the drives UUID it normally doesn't change (unless you make a new filesystem and don't provide this number again as an option).

You can use that UUID to mount instead of the device when mounting:

```
mount UUID=xyz /home/media
```

or insert that `UUID=xyz` in the first column of an `/etc/fstab` entry, then you can just do `mount /home/media`.

Alternatively you can assign a label to a filesystem (e.g. using the `-L` option for `mkfs.ext4` or `mkfs.btrfs` and use `LABEL=thelabelyouspecified` in a similar fashion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I am going to try this tonight :D

Comment: Just a quick thing I noticed, when I try: ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid | fgrep /dev/sdc1 (fdisk -l shows that it's on /dev/sdc1) I don't get any output.

Comment: @SanderKoenders did you mount it first? If not mounted there will be no entry in that directory.

Comment: I tried both mounted and unmounted, I already got the UUID by running ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid only though :D

Comment: @SanderKoenders You should put that in your `/etc/fstab` as that makes solving the problem in your other question more easy. But you can try first with a manual `mount UUID=xyz /home/media`.

Comment: I could not wait for tonight so I decided to do it now. I put the following in fstab `UUID=3b82c316-e507-4fdf-a4ad-9a77882362fb /home/media/externalHardDrive ext4 noauto,user 0 2`. I am not rly sure what these last 2 parameters do though, I understand that they check the filesystem but I don't know for what. Anyhow, from what I can see now the scripts work perfectly fine. without sudo.

Comment: The fifth field is for `dump` and nowadays seldom used. The sixth for the order of mounting (i.e. `/` needs to be mounted before `/home` etc).

Comment: Ah, so I don't really have to worry about them I assume?

Comment: No `0 2` should be fine, especially since `noauto` is specified and the drive not mounted on bootup anyway ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `udev` for mounting the hard drives. It will automate the task and make identification a lot easier. If connected device is a hard drive, there will be a `$ID_ATA=1` variable in your script.

Comment: Well the problem is that it has to be easy for my father to dismount. So I made a simple web interface which runs these scripts.

Comment: Mouting will be done automatic – just connect the drive. If it is USB and is a hard drive - then mount. Unmounting you can make as your father like. Multiple drives are supported.